# Downloading files from FTP failing

Tags: php, ftp

I checked over some other answers before I came here to publish a question, I'm having trouble with the following script, no matter what i've tried it will not download a file from the FTP even after listing the files that are in directory (obviously)

Because I'm organised I like to simplify everything into a class,

```
class FTPHandler
{
    private $connection;

    public function FTPConnect($host, $user, $pass)
    {
        $ftp = ftp_connect($host);
        $login = ftp_login($ftp, $user, $pass) or die("FTP: Login Failed");
        if ($login) {
            $this->connection = array("host" => $host, "user" => $user, "pass" => $pass);
            return $ftp;
        }

        echo "FTP Login Failed";
    }
    public function ListAllFiles($stream, $dir)
    {
        ftp_pasv($stream, true);
        $ls = ftp_nlist($stream, $dir);
        return $ls;
    }

    public function get_conx_info() {
        return $this->connection;
    }
}
```

Using the following code:

```
define("APP_DIR", "./app/");

$ftp = new FTPHandler();

$handle = $ftp->FTPConnect("ftp.example.com.au", "exampleuser", "examplepass");

$files = $ftp->ListAllFiles($handle, APP_DIR);

foreach ($files as $val)
{
    if ($val != "." && $val != ".." && $val != "processed") {

        $local_file     =   $val;
        $remote_file    =   APP_DIR.$val;

        if (ftp_get($handle, $local_file, $remote_file)) {
            echo "Successfully retrieved: $remote_file <br/>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "Failed retrieving file: $remote_file <br/>";
        }

    }
}
```

My return is always:

```
Failed retrieving file: ./app/adsl-1989-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/adsl-1989-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1964-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1964-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1967-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1967-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1972-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1972-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1973-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1973-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1974-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1974-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1975-csv.csv 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1975-sig.png 
Failed retrieving file: ./app/dd-1978-csv.csv
```

Any assistance is highly appreciated as I have to have this automated to alleviate a few thousand per week off the employee budget.

Comment: If running the script from the root, try `define("APP_DIR", "app/");` if outside a sub-folder, `define("APP_DIR", "../app/");` or a full server path `define("APP_DIR", "/var/user/you/public_html/app/");` depending on where `app` is located.

Comment: The ftp account is setup so that all it can see is the app folder and its contents, I wonder if this prevents me from using absolute paths as I had no success with the above suggestions. `$ftp->ListAllFiles($handle, APP_DIR);` works as intended so the path from root is definitely `./app/`

Comment: `define("APP_DIR", "../../../../../../../../../app/");` Even this lists the files within APP directory so most definitely at root level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up discovering that the FTP server itself was at fault.

The error was fixed by changing from the default Active Ports as it was dropping majority of packets.

So if anyone out there is experiencing the same issue, worth taking a look at doing the same.

Thank you to [Fred -ii-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1415724/fred-ii) for your attempt in assisting me.

Comment: How did you fix this issue on server end? Please assist me.